# There should be a way to gain a little reputation for newbies

Tags: support, reputation, new-users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to earn rep when unable to answer quickly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92577/best-way-to-earn-rep-when-unable-to-answer-quickly)

I have been getting a lot of help from reading the stack overflow answers to android/java questions.  My issue is that the problems that I have encountered have all been asked and answered.  So, I don't ask questions and I don't provide answers so that my reputation doesn't change.

I wouldn't care, except that I am getting such good help from some of the answers, that I would really like to be able to vote up the answers.

How do I get myself to reputation 15 in my situation so that I can participate at least enough to say thank you?

Or am I missing something?

Thank you.

Comment: **at least enough to say thank you** <-- Please don't do this. I know it's polite in most places but on SE it's only clutter and discouraged. An upvote/marked as correct answer is all the thanks needed.

Answer (score 5):

- Ask good questions. Make it really easy for folks to help you, and many will show their gratitude with upvotes.
- Get good enough in your preferred subject area to answer knowledgeably and well. Revel in upvotes.
- [Suggest edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) to existing questions and answers. Each edit you write, and is accepted, nets you +2 rep. Find a post that could stand to be improved and click the `improve this question` link.